# How do I concatenate variable to object in vba access?

Tags: ms-access, vba, concatenation

I'm trying to create a function that would allow me to pass in a variable that gets added to an object.  I want to be able to move a row of values up to the next line in a Form.  I want to add a variable so that I don't have to keep repeating the same code for every single row.

```
Function UpArrow(x As Variant, y As Variant)
  Dim TextContent As String
  cboOperation +x+ .Value = TextContent
  cboOperation +x+ .Value = cboOperation +y+ .Value
  cboOperation +y+ .Value = TextContent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the Controls collection.

```
Function UpArrow(x As Variant, y As Variant)
    Dim TextContent As String
    TextContent = Controls("cboOperation" & x).value
    Controls("cboOperation" & x).value = Controls("cboOperation" & y).value
    Controls("cboOperation" & y).value = TextContent
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks that was it!